# MONGO DB updating nested array

Tags: mongodb

```js
Below Array this Exisiting in DataBase and
[{
    name: 'Courier Received by Investor',
    value: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Courier Sent By Investor',
    value: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Signed CA-Doc received',
    value: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Cheque/Payment Received',
    value: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Cancelled Cheque Received',
    value: false
  },
  {
    name: 'ID Proof Received',
    value: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Address Proof Received',
    value: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Signed CA pictures/scan received',
    value: false
  }
]


 I WANT TO UPDATE THESE BELOW FIELDS IN THE ABOVE ARRAY, CAN ANYONE HELP ME WITH THIS?


[{
    name: 'Courier Received by Investor',
    value: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Courier Sent By Investor',
    value: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Cheque/Payment Received',
    value: true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) with a [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array).

For example, assuming you created your document has the following structure (`arrayField` is the field name used to hold your array values):

```
{
    arrayField: [{
            name: 'Courier Received by Investor',
            value: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Courier Sent By Investor',
            value: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Signed CA-Doc received',
            value: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Cheque/Payment Received',
            value: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Cancelled Cheque Received',
            value: false
        },
        {
            name: 'ID Proof Received',
            value: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Address Proof Received',
            value: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Signed CA pictures/scan received',
            value: false
        }
    ]
}
```

You could update all entries for a `Courier Sent By Investor` and set it to `true` as follows:

```
db.collection.update({}, {
    $set: {
        "arrayField.$[element].value": true
    }
}, {
    multi: true,
    arrayFilters: [{
        "element.name": "Courier Sent By Investor"
    }]
})
```